# How can I implement pagination when I want to order by a dynamically calculated property?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, pagination

I have an endpoint that returns a list of "Order" objects for a commerce app. Each order can have a number of items attached, each with its own cost; because there is no guarantee that the items' individual cost will not change until the order is placed, the Total Cost for each order is being calculated on the server and then appended to the returned results.

I am now trying to add pagination to this endpoint, and it is my understanding that pagination should always be left to the database when possible. I also get that in order for pagination to work properly, the results must be ordered in the same manner for every page.

You can probably guess where I'm having an issue, how can I implement pagination here when I can only get the element I'd like to order by AFTER I receive my results.

I could simply retrieve all the results in the query and perform the pagination on the server using `Skip()` and `Take()`, but that seems incredibly inefficient and probably not the best solution. Any advice on what I could do, besides disabling ordering by that specific property entirely?

Answer (score 0):

By using row_number() you can assign SerialNo to all rows
and you can take input from-to and can take data as
SerialNo between from and to